# Find the Top Level for each item in a hierarchical relationship in Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, hierarchical-data

I am trying to query a (large) Oracle 9 table that represents some hierarchical data. The Parent items have their own Id as Parent ID.  As an example;

```
ID    PARENTID               
----- --------  
1     1
2     1
3     2
4     2
5     3
6     6
7     6
8     6
9     4
10    10
```

I want to have a query that returns each ID, along with the ultimate Parent for that ID, so continuing my example

```
ID    UlitimateParent
----  ----
1     1
2     1
3     1
4     1
5     1
6     6
7     6
8     6
9     1
10    10
```

I've seen a few examples using Connect By but can't seem to get this to work.  Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 10g+, you would use the [`CONNECT_BY_ROOT`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/Hierarchical-Query-Operators.htm#SQLRF51161) function:

```
SQL> with data as (
  2     SELECT 1 id, 1 parent_id FROM DUAL
  3     UNION ALL SELECT 2 , 1  FROM DUAL
  4     UNION ALL SELECT 3 , 2  FROM DUAL
  5     UNION ALL SELECT 4 , 2  FROM DUAL
  6     UNION ALL SELECT 5 , 3  FROM DUAL
  7     UNION ALL SELECT 6 , 6  FROM DUAL
  8     UNION ALL SELECT 7 , 6  FROM DUAL
  9     UNION ALL SELECT 8 , 6  FROM DUAL
 10     UNION ALL SELECT 9 , 4  FROM DUAL
 11     UNION ALL SELECT 10, 10 FROM DUAL
 12  )
 13  SELECT id, connect_by_root(id) ultimate_parent_id
 14    FROM data
 15  START WITH id = parent_id
 16  CONNECT BY parent_id = PRIOR id AND id != PRIOR id  ;

ID  ULTIMATE_PARENT_ID
--- ------------------
  1                  1
  2                  1
  3                  1
  5                  1
  4                  1
  9                  1
  6                  6
  7                  6
  8                  6
 10                 10
```

In 9i, you could use [`SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96540/functions121a.htm#SQLRF06116) (with appropriate substring):

```
SQL> with data as (
  2     SELECT 1 id, 1 parent_id FROM DUAL
  3     UNION ALL SELECT 2 , 1  FROM DUAL
  4     UNION ALL SELECT 3 , 2  FROM DUAL
  5     UNION ALL SELECT 4 , 2  FROM DUAL
  6     UNION ALL SELECT 5 , 3  FROM DUAL
  7     UNION ALL SELECT 6 , 6  FROM DUAL
  8     UNION ALL SELECT 7 , 6  FROM DUAL
  9     UNION ALL SELECT 8 , 6  FROM DUAL
 10     UNION ALL SELECT 9 , 4  FROM DUAL
 11     UNION ALL SELECT 10, 10 FROM DUAL
 12  )
 13  SELECT id, sys_connect_by_path(id, '->') path
 14    FROM data
 15  START WITH id = parent_id
 16  CONNECT BY parent_id = PRIOR id
 17         AND id != PRIOR id;

        ID PATH
---------- --------------------
         1 ->1
         2 ->1->2
         3 ->1->2->3
         5 ->1->2->3->5
         4 ->1->2->4
         9 ->1->2->4->9
         6 ->6
         7 ->6->7
         8 ->6->8
        10 ->10
```

Comment: You can also use `nocycle` parameter instead of additional comparison `AND id != PRIOR id`.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov not in 9i :)

Comment: Your first query aimed at 10g+.  :)

Answer (score 2):

I just learned this, thanks to your question :)

You could use

```
replace(sys_connect_by_path(decode(level, 1, id), '~'), '~')
```

to replace the connect_by_root function prior to 10g.

```
with data1 as (
   SELECT 1 id, 1 parent_id FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL SELECT 2 , 1  FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL SELECT 3 , 2  FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL SELECT 4 , 2  FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL SELECT 5 , 3  FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL SELECT 6 , 6  FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL SELECT 7 , 6  FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL SELECT 8 , 6  FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL SELECT 9 , 4  FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL SELECT 10, 10 FROM DUAL
) 
SELECT id, replace(sys_connect_by_path(decode(level,
                                               1, id), '~'), '~') 
            ultimate_parent_id
  FROM data1
  START WITH id = parent_id
  CONNECT BY parent_id = PRIOR id AND id != PRIOR id  ;

ID      PATH
--------------
1   1
2   1
3   1
5   1
4   1
9   1
6   6
7   6
8   6
10  10
```